# Who doesn't love cats?

Tags: riddle

> Peta cat on the sidewalk when they do this
>   The A's never did this back when I sold 'em
>   I could be a startup that wasn't good at business
>   When you see the three, you'd better hold 'em

What am I?

There are 5 clues in this riddle, and each must be identified and explained to get the check!

Hints:

> The first clue is in the first line: "Peta" is not a typo.
>  The second clue is something cats do on the side walk, usually to scratch their back.
>  I am a four letter word

Comment: Peta = pet a? Typo or clue?

Comment: It's not a typo.

Comment: (hey solvers, you might wanna click edit)

Comment: Clever hidden formatting :)

Comment: I added another clue :-)

Comment: That's pretty clever!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is

> flop

Peta cat on the sidewalk when they do this

> Cats can flop onto their backs to scratch themselves.  You can pet a cat while it is doing this.  In addition, "peta" can refer to a petaflop, which in computing is one quadrillion floating point operations per second.

The A's never did this back when I sold 'em

> This is referring to the A drive on a computer, which used to be a 3.5" floppy drive.  3.5" disks weren't actually floppy.  (Thanks DylanSp.)

I could be a startup that wasn't good at business

> Anything that fails can be said to be a flop.

When you see the three, you'd better hold 'em

> This is referring to the 3 face up "flop" cards in the game of Texas hold 'em.

Comment: Can you add those 5 clues (about which everyone knows) to complete the answer. This answer seems right to me. +1

Comment: @manshu I am actually not sure why certain clues were labeled as such, as they don't seem like clues to me.

Comment: I don't know either. But I was saying just because it was the requirement of the question.

Comment: You've got most of the clues, but the A's is a little off. I'm sure a *drive*n individual will be able to help.

Comment: @the A's clue: is it referring to the fact that the A: drive was customarily used for 3.5'' disks, which weren't actually floppy (despite the name)?

Comment: @DylanSp That would be correct! :)

Comment: Thanks @DylanSp.  On my old computers, the 3.5" floppy drive was the B drive, and the 5.25" floppy drive was the A drive.

Comment: @pacoverflow: Be careful when petting a cat in the situation you describe; if the cat doesn't know you very well, it is likely to bite and scratch you (more so than if you stroke it along its spine or rub its chin). You may be fusing clue1 and clue2 more than you're intended to.

Comment: @corsiKa: If pacoverflow's initial answer was wrong for clue3, and the revised answer is correct, what does "back when I sold 'em" have to do with it?

Comment: @PeregrineRook Have you tried to buy 3.5" floppy disks lately? I doubt they're a hot seller these days... Specifically, it means the A's were something that are obsolete.